# Spring boot Oauth2 grant_type password always return invalid_grant Bad Credentials

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I am trying to create an API that is in charge of securing the rest of my APIs. This api has the functionality of **generating the token for the users** of the whole set.
Users must authenticate by clientId and secrt and with their username and password.
To test it I am using a postman request like this:

```
  curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:5101/oauth/token' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic cHJ1ZWJhOnBydWViYQ==' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'username=usuario' \
--data-urlencode 'password=pass' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=all'
```

The authorization header is composed of the clientId and its secret key.

I always get **invalid_grant error** when **grant_type** is **password**

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Bad credentials"
}
```

When I use the grant_type client_credentials it works fine, it returns the client token.

This is my **Main** class

```
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class Auth implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Auth.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String password = "pass";
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            String pasBcript = passwordEncoder.encode(password);
            System.out.println(pasBcript);
        }
    }
}
```

I have used run method to obtain passwords for my database users.

**SecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    // @Autowired private AuthenticationEventPublisher eventPublisher;
    
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        //.and().authenticationEventPublisher(eventPublisher);
    }
    
    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

**AuthorizationServerConfig**

```
@RefreshScope
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{
    
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()") //Endpoint para generar el token public, POST /oauth/token
        .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()"); // validar el toekn
    }

    // Doble autenticacion cliente (aplicacion) y usuarios
    // hay que envioar dos crecenciales las de la aplicacion y las del usuario
    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()      
        .withClient("prueba")
        .secret(passwordEncoder.encode("prueba"))
        .scopes("all") // Permiso de la app prueba
        .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token", "client_credentials") // Tipo de autenticación, como vamos a obtener el token
        .accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600)
        .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(3600);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        
        TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(accessTokenConverter()));
        
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
        .tokenStore(tokenStore()) // Componente que se encarga de guardar el token
        .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
        .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter tokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        // Codigo secreto para firmar
        tokenConverter.setSigningKey(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(env.getProperty("config.security.oauth.jwt.key").getBytes()));
        return tokenConverter;
    }
    
}
```

**UserService**

```
@Service
public class UserService implements IUserService, UserDetailsService {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserService.class);
    

    @Autowired
    private IUserRepository userRepository;
    @Override
    public AuthUser loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
    }

}
```

**POM.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.11</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>net.example.auth</groupId>
    <artifactId>auth-service</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Auth</name>
    <description></description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I'm sure the credentials are fine, both for the client and for the user. I have checked it several times.
I already ran out of ideas, any help please??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in **userRepository**, I was looking for users by *username*, and in my database the *username* is the login field. I have changed username to login in the repository and now it works correctly.